# what is the name for equal sign (=) in windows virtual key, UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

[image: Sum or equal symbol]

what is the name for equal or sum sign (=) in windows virtual key, in UWP? I've been searching for this symbol under Windows.System.VirtualKey enumerations for 50 years already and yet I still couldn't get a clue, please to all geniuses out there save my life..Please

Comment: It is one of the OEM keys, intentionally unnamed in the VirtualKey enumeration.  The keyboard manufacturer can put it anywhere he prefers.  Not just an arbitrary limitation, if you hit that key on, say, a Spanish keyboard then you get an upside-down exclamation mark, only Shift+0 produces the "=" character.  So you are probably using the wrong event if you are interested in detecting it, use the CoreWindow.CharacterReceived event instead.

Comment: thank you masta.. I learned a lot here :)

Answer (score 3):

I do not see Enum for **=** in [Official Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey.aspx) but when i use KeyDownEvent, It enumerated to value **187**

[image: EnumValue]

Comment: Thank you brother.. you just showed me another way to discover VirtualKey enum value :).. very helpful thanks again